# module 'cloud_firestore' not found (Flutter)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

I am having this error when I am building my app with Xcode 'module 'cloud_firestore' not found. [enter image description here][1] I have updated my Cocoapods to 1.9.3 and I updated the flutter to 1.17.3, but still is not working and I am opening the file.xcworkspace.

Also, these are the versions of my dependencies:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  charts_flutter: ^0.8.1

  flutter_picker:
    git: git://github.com/yangyxd/flutter_picker.git
  flutter_cupertino_data_picker: ^0.8.6
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
  #firebase_analytics: ^5.0.9
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.1 
  provider: ^4.0.4
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10
  firebase_database: ^3.1.3 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPc71.png
```

Comment: use the last version :https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/versions

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the firestore version:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
```

Answer (score 7):

from [this](https://fantashit.com/module-cloud-firestore-not-found-impossible-to-publish-app-on-apple-app-store/)

For anyone who is facing the problem when “Archiving” or trying to publish to the Apple Store:

Make sure to have all projects closed in Xcode
Open “Runner.xcworkspace” not runner.xcodeproj
You have to make sure that runner.xcodeproj is not open at the same time with workspace.

This is also assuming that you have run and built successfully prior to making an archive.

Comment: Could build and install fine with flutter terminal commands but Xcode would not work. I spent over an hour cleaning caches, rebuilding, checking versions, and a bunch of other solutions to finally come across this and facepalm. Open the workspace and not the project and everything worked perfect. As an FYI, this was just for test running on a device or simulator. So make sure to open the workspace.

Comment: you saved my day Apple making developers so hard ..